# How to GET a .jpg image using XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I can easily grab a .txt file for example using this method but when I try to get an image it sends a bunch of unencoded letters like these �@R�J�, how can I get the image as it is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1 id="demo">Let AJAX change this text</h1>

<button id="button">Change Content</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', function(){

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "images.jpg", true);
  xhttp.send();

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit:**

I have actually figured out I can do this `document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute('src', 'https://placeimg.com/640/480/any');`

and in the HTML `<img id="demo" src="" />`

And it works fine for an external resource but what about an image that's living in my server?

Comment: what is your server side, PHP ?

Comment: I'm not doing any server side lifting and the image is just sitting there in a folder so no php or any other server side language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the image is on your server you can get it by absolute address `src="http://localhost:portnumber/pathOfTheImage/image.png"` or relatively to your site folder, `src="/images/image.png"`.